# Typescript: Infer function argument

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, conditional-types

Ever Since TS 2.8, we can do the following:

```
type ArgType<F> = F extends (a: infer A) => any ? A : any

const fn: (s: string) => 500

ArgType<(typeof fn> // => string
```

Let's assume the following situation.

```
type FunctionCollection = {
  [key: string]: (s: ???) => any
}

const fnCol: FunctionCollection = {
    someFn: (s: string) => 500
}
```

**Question:** Is there any way to replace `???` (or the whole of FunctionCollection) with a type such that

```
ArgType<(typeof fnCol)["someFn"]> 'equals' string
```

*(The issue is that for example, if `??? = any`, we get `any`)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the argument type can be different for each property of the type, you will need a type argument:

```
type FunctionCollection<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: (s: T[P]) => any
}
```

Now to create such a variable you would need to specify the properties as the type argument to `FunctionCollection` which is less then ideal:

```
const fnColNoInference: FunctionCollection<{
    someFn: string;
    otherFn: number;
}> = {
    someFn: (s: string) => 500,
    otherFn: (s: number) => 500
}
```

A better approach is to use the inference behavior of functions to infer the type of the constant:

```
function functionCollection<T>(args: FunctionCollection<T>) {
    return args
}

const fnCol = functionCollection({
    someFn: (s: string) => 500,
    otherFn: (s: number) => 500
})

let d : ArgType<(typeof fnCol)["someFn"]> // is string 
let d2 : ArgType<(typeof fnCol)["otherFn"]> // is number
```

Comment: Nice! I had already used the first solution in my case but came here for a better one. I like the second one! However, I realised that this does not solve my actual problem. I will post a follow up.